# How to setup java cv in eclipse for android

Tags: android, opencv, javacv

Can some one tell me how should i set up java cv in eclipse to use android image processing programme.what are the steps i should follow when installing java cv.I need to know is open cv can use in eclipse also.
Thanks for the help..!!

Answer (score 1):

There is a tutorial by OpenCV in their official tutorial about this :

[Using Android binary package with Eclipse](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package.html#android-binary-package)

Hope it works.

Comment: Without Installing Cygwin Can i do this task in other way ??